# wordpress query_posts problem

Tags: wordpress

So I have a custom template that display posts from a particular category (depending on the get_post_meta('Category')).

The page works flawlessly for displaying posts from a 'News' Category. However, using the exact same code (minus how its displayed), it has problems with the Pagination for posts from the Calendar Category. Basically, the first page of Calendar posts display correctly, and then when you hit 'next page', the url updates to page/2, but the same posts are on the page.

Here's the code:

```
<?php $category = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Category', true); ?>
<?php $cat = get_cat_ID($category); ?>

<?php $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1; ?>

<?php $args = array(
        'cat' => $cat,
        'paged' => $paged
    );
?>

<?php query_posts($args); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <!-- If its a Calendar page -->
        <?php if ($cat == 1): ?>
            <div class='entry'>
                <!-- List all Calendar info and Custom Fields -->
                <ul>
                    <li><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></li>
                    <li><?php the_content(); ?></li>

            <!-- ...And displays other data, etc..... -->
                </ul>
            </div>

        <?php else: ?>

            <div class='entry'>
                <ul>
                    <li><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3></li>
                    <li><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></li>
                    <li><?php the_content(); ?></li>

            <!-- And display other data, etc .... -->
                </ul>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <!-- Posts Nav Links -->
    <?php posts_nav_link(' | ', '&laquo; Newer Entries', 'Older Entries &raquo;'); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely this has to do with how you are setting the `paged` parameter for `query_posts()` in a custom template.

Read more about this here: http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/right-way-to-use-query_posts.html

In a nutshell you may need to use `get_query_var('paged')`.

Comment: hm thats really interesting.  Right now, im using get_query_var('page') and it works with News but not Calendar.  If I switch to get_query_var('paged'), then the opposite is true!  Any idea why?

Comment: Actually just read.  Because News is set as the homepage, it uses 'page'.  Thats how that works (for some reason).  Everything else uses 'paged'.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. Thanks for following up on why you were having an issue with 'News'. That may help someone in the future.